# List of Dicts comparision to match between lists and detect value changes in Python

Tags: python, comparison, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I get back from a web service call,

```
listA = [{'name':'foo', 'val':'x'}, 
         {'name':'bar', 'val':'1'},
         {'name':'alice','val':'2'}]
```

I need to compare the results from the previous call to the service and pull out changes. So on the next call I may get:

```
listB = [{'name':'foo', 'val':'y'},
         {'name':'bar', 'val':'1'},
         {'name':'eve','val':'z'}]
```

The ordering is not guaranteed and nor is the length of list. The names won't change. The actual data has several more keys, but I'm only concerned with 'val'.

I am trying to find a way to get back a list of the names that have had their values change between calls only for the names that are in both lists.

```
changed = ['foo'] # or [{'name':'foo'}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd build an auxiliary dict to store `listA`'s information more sensibly:

```
auxdict = dict((d['name'], d['val']) for d in listA)
```

then the task becomes very easy:

```
changed = [d['name'] for d in listB 
           if d['name'] in auxdict and d['val'] != auxdict[d['name']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, please turn that braindead format from your library into a real dict:

```
>>> listA = [{'name':'foo', 'val':'x'},{'name':'bar', 'val':'1'},{'name':'alice','val':'2'}]
>>> listB = [{'name':'foo', 'val':'y'},{'name':'bar', 'val':'1'},{'name':'eve','val':'z'}]
>>> def dicter(l):
...     return dict([(i['name'],i['val']) for i in l])
...
>>> listA=dicter(listA)
>>> listA
{'foo': 'x', 'bar': '1', 'alice': '2'}
>>> listB=dicter(listB)
>>> listB
{'foo': 'y', 'bar': '1', 'eve': 'z'}
```

Then, this becomes relatively easy:

```
>>> answer = [k for k,v in listB.items() if k in listA and listA[k] != v]
>>> answer
['foo']
>>>
```

Comment: You might consider skipping the intermediate list by using a generator in your `dicter` function: `dict([(i['name'],i['val']) for i in l])` becomes `dict( (i['name'],i['val']) for i in l)`