# 'if' element is not in list on Google App Engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am building an application for Facebook using Google App Engine. I was trying to compare friends in my user's Facebook account to those already in my application, so I could add them to the database if they are friends in Facebook but not in my application, or not if they are already friends in both. I was trying something like this:

```
request = graph.request("/me/friends")
user = User.get_by_key_name(self.session.id)
list = []
for x in user.friends:
    list.append(x.user)

for friend in request["data"]:
    if User.get_by_key_name(friend["id"]):
        friendt = User.get_by_key_name(friend["id"])
        if friendt.key not in user.friends:
            newfriend = Friend(friend = user,
                               user = friendt,
                               id = friendt.id)
            newfriend.put()
```

`graph.request` returns an object with the user's friends. How do I compare content in te two lists of retrieved objects. It doesn't necessarily need to be Facebook related.

(I know this question may be quite silly, but it is really being a pain for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to NDB, the "in" operator will actually work; NDB implements a proper **eq** operator on Model instances.  Note that the key is also compared, so entities that have the same property values but different keys are considered unequal.  If you want to ignore the key, consider comparing e1._to_dict() == e2._to_dict().

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom function to compare your objects, and consider it as a comparison of nested dictionaries. As you will be comparing only the attributes and not functions, you have to do a nested dict comparison. 
Reason: All the attributes will be not callable and hopefully, might not start with _, so you have to just compare the remaining elements from the obj.**dict** and the approach should be bottom up i.e. finish off the nested level objects first (e.g. the main object could host other objects, which will have their own **dict**)

Lastly, you can consider the accepted answer code here: [How to compare two lists of dicts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333530/how-to-compare-two-lists-of-dicts-in-python)